# Why am I obtaining this error message trying to import a .csv file into a MariaDB table?

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, rdbms, csv-import

I am trying to import a **.csv** file content into a **Maria DB** table but I am finding some difficulties. I am working into a Linux Ubuntu environment.

I have the following situation. This is my **Status** table:

```
MariaDB [Delphys]> describe Status;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| StatusID    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Status      | char(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| StatusGroup | char(3)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| text        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| TestText01  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| TestText02  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.106 sec)
```

And this is the content of the file that I am trying to import into the previous table:

```
1;A;ABC;Existing sensors, already linked to DCS/DeltaV;Defalt value;Simulated input value
2;B;ABC;Existing sensors, already linked to DCS to be linked to DeltaV;Simulated value;Simulated input value
3;C;ABC;Sensors to be installed and linked to DCS/DeltaV;Simulated value;Simulated input value
4;D;D  ;Calculated Value without Model and GPA;expected result without Model and GPA;expected result without Model and GPA
5;E;E  ;Calculated Values after Establishment of Engine Model and GPA;expected result after Establishment of Engine Model and GPA;expected result after Establishment of Engine Model and GPA
```

I performed the following command into MariaDB console and I am obtaining the following error message:

```
MariaDB [Delphys]> LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql/Status.csv'
    -> INTO TABLE Status
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    -> ;
ERROR 1366 (22007): Incorrect integer value: '??1' for column `Delphys`.`Status`.`StatusID` at row 1
```

A doubt is that my **.csv** file is generated by a Windows machine that maybe handling the newline in different way (but it seems strange to me).

What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I correctly import my **.csv** file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `INTO TABLE table` i.e. into which table the CSV-file should be inserted.

Comment: I correct the command using the "INTO TABLE ..." but now I am obtaining another error. I have edited my original post

Comment: Sounds like you have invisible characters in beginning of the file (most likely BOM, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).